# how to play you tube video within my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

i have placed a picture in my android activity. when user taps on that picture i want a you tube video should be played within my app.

currently, it redirects the user to you tube app or browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the YouTube Android player API which enables you to incorporate video playback in your application.

You can [download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) the API client library, [register](https://console.developers.google.com/project) your application in the Google Developer console and there are some [sample application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) you can follow.

More details can be found at developer portal: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/